# Yup Validation for Dropdown : React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am creating React based application and using Yup for validation. However I get an error of `Cyclic Dependency` while validating.

**Explanation:**
Users will see two drop down list of colors as seen in the image below.
By default Both the drop down will have `White` as selected.

**Note** By default on page load, `White - White` will be the given option. This selection is valid.

**Scenarios:** User are about to start drawing and now they are selecting colors from the drop down list.

**Example:**

1. White  - White : **OK**
2. White - Red : **Error:**(You must select other
   color, cannot select white in 1st drop down)
3. Red - White: **Error:**(You
   must select other color, cannot select white in 2nd drop down)
4. Red - Red : **Error:**(Cannot select two same colors except White for both
   drop down)
5. Red - Green: **OK**
6. Green - Red: **OK**
7. yellow - Red: **OK**
8. yellow - White: **Error**(You must select other color, cannot select
   white in 2nd drop down)

I am trying to start the first validation but it seems there is a problem of `Cyclic Dependency`. I'd appreciate your help. Thanks.

[image]

```
FirstColorDDL:""
SecondColorDDL:""
```

```
const Color = () => {
    return Yup.object().shape({
        FirstColorDDL: Yup.string()
            .required('Please Choose any Color !!'),
            .when("SecondColorDDL", {
            is: (SecondColorDDL) => SecondColorDDL && SecondColorDDL == "White",
            then: Yup.string().required("You must select other color, cannot select white in 2nd drop down")
            }),
        SecondColorDDL: Yup.string()
            .required('Please Choose any Color !!'),
            .when("FirstColorDDL", {
            is: (FirstColorDDL) => !FirstColorDDL|| FirstColorDDL.contains("White"),
            then: Yup.string().required("You must select other color, cannot select white in 1st drop down")
         })

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.when`, you can use `.test` and reference other fields using `context.parent`:

```
FirstColorDDL: Yup.string()
  .required('Please Choose any Color !!'),
  .test({
    name: 'notWhite',
    message: 'You must select other color, cannot select white in 1st drop down',
    test: (value, context) => value === 'white' && context.parent.SecondColorDDL !== 'white'
  }),

SecondColorDDL: Yup.string()
  .required('Please Choose any Color !!'),
  .test({
    name: 'notWhite',
    message: 'You must select other color, cannot select white in 2nd drop down',
    test: (value, context) => value === 'white' && context.parent.FirstColorDDL!== 'white'
  }),
```

You can also use `test` to implement the remaining rule from your example.